# Test of association and Logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, chi-squared-test

Hi I have 9 predictor variables and 1 binary dependent variable. After running chi-square test of association, 8 out of 9 are significantly associated to the dependent variable. My question is, should I run all the 8 predictor variables in binary logistic regression simultaneously or individually? Thank you! I am a starter statistician handling clients.

Comment: (1) I hope you have an *enormous* amount of data, because 9 or 10 degrees of freedom are a *very* complex model. (2) We can't tell you. It may well be that your predictors carry a lot of common information. E.g., if you model children's cognitive abilities on age, height and weight, then all three predictors may be significant - but height and weight are probably mostly significant because they are proxies for age. So: please include more information, by editing your post. Thank you!

Comment: The limiting factor in logistic regression is essentially the number of observations in the lower-frequency outcome class. That determines the complexity of the model you can reasonably contemplate. When you edit the question as requested, please include information on the numbers in each outcome class. Also, please say how you (or your clients) intend to use the model, as the approaches can be somewhat different depending on whether the primary interest is in inference or prediction. Information about the natures of the predictor variables (continuous, ordinal, categorical) would help, too.

Comment: Another point worth mentioning is that the lack of statistical significance of that ninth variable does not necessarily mean that it should be excluded from the full regression. If you do this kind of univariate screening before you fit the full regression, you risk altering the downstream inferences.